# LCD and RTC_DS1307- Unable to print the 1-9 digit seconds on the lcd correctly

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am connected my RTC module and LCD to my Arduino. The time print correctly, however when it is e.g. 10:13:09 in real time, on the lcd it gets printed out as 10:13:19. When it gets to 10:13:10 it prints out fine.
Example:
10:13:58

10:13:59

10:14:10

10:14:11 ...  Here is the problem

10:14:19 Here is the problem

10:14:10

10:14:11... etc

My code for this (not sure where I am going wrong):

```
 //time displayed on lcd
lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
lcd.print(now.hour(), DEC);
lcd.print(':');
lcd.print(now.minute(), DEC);
lcd.print(':');
if(Serial.print(now.second(), DEC) >= 10){
   lcd.setCursor(10,0);
   lcd.print(now.second(), DEC);
}
else if(Serial.print(now.second(), DEC) < 10){
  lcd.setCursor(11,0);
  lcd.print(now.second(), DEC);
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print(" ");
}
```

Could someone help me with this code please?

Comment: [Serial.::print returns the number of bytes written](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) You are then comparing the number of bytes written to 10. Not sure that's what you want.

Comment: When seconds < 10, both Serial.print and lcd.print is going to print a single digit.  You've compensated by printing that digit in the right location, but you didn't change the digit left in the "tens" position.  You need to print a leading 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shoud by:

```
 //time displayed on lcd
lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
lcd.print(now.hour(), DEC);
lcd.print(':');
lcd.print(now.minute(), DEC);
lcd.print(':');
if(now.second() >= 10){
   lcd.setCursor(10,0);
   lcd.print(now.second(), DEC);
}
else if(now.second() < 10){
  lcd.setCursor(11,0);
  lcd.print(now.second(), DEC);
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print(" ");
}
```

Remove Serial.print inside the if
Serial.print(now.second(), DEC) returns the number of bytes sended to the serial port. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print
It is not usefull here.